Let $(X,t)$ be a topological space and let $f_1,f_2:X\to \mathbb R$ show that $\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}} $ is continuous
I am attempting to prove the following:
Let $(X,t)$ be a topological space and let $f_1,f_2:X\to \mathbb R$ be continuous functions such that:
$\forall x\in X: f_2(x)\not=0$, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb R:\alpha f_1,\alpha f_2,f_1+f_2$ are continuous show that $\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}} $ is continuous.
Attempt: we will show that the inverse map of every closed set is closed, let $D\subset \mathbb R$ be a closed set, looking at $\left(\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}\right)^{-1}\left(D\right)$ we get:
$\left(\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}\right)^{-1}\left(D\right)=\left\{ x\in X\mid\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}\left(x\right)\in D\right\} =\left\{ x\in X\mid\frac{f_{1}\left(x\right)}{f_{2}\left(x\right)}\in D\right\} =\left\{ x\in X\mid f_{1}\left(x\right)=c\cdot f_{2}\left(x\right),c\in D\right\} =\left\{ x\in X\mid f_{1}\left(x\right)-c\cdot f_{2}\left(x\right)=0,c\in D\right\}$
Notice that if we define: $h(x)=f_{1}\left(x\right)-c\cdot f_{2}\left(x\right)=0$ its clearly continuous by the assumption and since $\left\{ 0\right\} $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ under the normal topology induced by the metric clearly: $h^{-1}\left(\left\{ 0\right\} \right)=\left\{ x\in X\mid f_{1}\left(x\right)-c\cdot f_{2}\left(x\right)=0\right\}$, is a closed set.
and going  backward we get $h^{-1}\left(\left\{ 0\right\} \right)=\dots=\left(\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}\right)^{-1}\left(D\right)$ hence $\left(\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}\right)^{-1}\left(D\right)$ is closed and $ \frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}}$ is continuous.
Is my attempt correct?

The proof is not correct, since you are only using that
$$ \left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right)^{-1}(D)=\cup_{c\in D} \left(f_1-cf_2\right)^{-1}(0)$$
Clearly, for each $c\in D$ we have $f_1-cf_2$ is continuous, so the inverse image of $0$ is closed. However, it is not said in general that the arbitrary union (labeled by $D$) is still closed.
Instead, I suggest to use the following method. We need two preliminary results:
$\textbf{Prop. 1}$
Given $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$, if $f$ and $g$ are continuos functions, then $g\circ f$ is a continuos function.
$\textbf{Prop. 2}$
Given two continuos functions $f_1\colon X\to Y$ and $f_2\colon X\to Y$, then the product function $(f_1,f_2)\colon X \to Y\times Y$ is continuos too.
$\textit{Proof}$ It is sufficient to prove it for each open set of a basis of $Y\times Y$, hence let us take $U\times V$ with $U$ and $V$ open sets of $Y$. Then
$$ (f_1,f_2)^{-1}(U\times V)=f_1^{-1}(U)\cap f_2^{-1}(V)$$
and so  $(f_1,f_2)^{-1}(U\times V)$ is an open set of $X$.
Now we can prove what you asked for:
$$\cdot \colon \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, \quad (a,b)\mapsto a\cdot b \qquad and \qquad (\cdot)^{-1} \colon \mathbb R\setminus {0}\to \mathbb R, \quad a\mapsto 1/a$$
are continuous maps.
Then you observe that $f_1/f_2$ can be written as the composition of the following continuos maps:
$$ \frac{f_1}{f_2}=\cdot \circ (Id_{\mathbb R}, (\cdot)^{-1})\circ (f_1,f_2). $$

I know that multiplacion and quotients are continuous in the spaces u wrote, I don't see how your suggestions helps when my domain is not $\mathbb R$

If you need more details, I can sketch you if you want :)

If u could sketch a prove I would apperciate that, cause I don't think I fully understood

nvm I understand it , thank your very much!

I have also added more details

ty, u have helped me a lot !
